# disadvantage of dividing fortran code into subroutines and its effect on speed?

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran90, intel-fortran

I have a Big FEM code. I have divided it into subroutines so it could further be sectioned and changed. My question is: why speed got slow.

1. Speed got slower when i divided code into subroutines
2. It got further slower when number of arguments were decreased (rearanged inside subroutine with extremely small computation).

Can somebody help me with some suggestions, how to optimize a fortran program when it is divided into subroutine. especially when that subroutine is called in a big loop.

Comment: No-one can help you without your code.

Comment: This question is basically unanswerable, downvote from me.

Comment: Interprocedural optimization should remove many of the performance implications of procedure calls.  Internal procedures give the compiler more opportunities, but this needn't be taken to excess.  For at least 25 years benchmarks have included tests of this.  To avoid depending on such optimizations you must localize vectorizable code and loops which need switching and unroll and jam inside the procedure. Collapse optimization (openmp or serial) might not be possible through procedure calls.

Comment: Are you using inlining?

Answer (score 0):

When a large monolithic code is divided into several parts, each of which is called perhaps millions of times, the overhead cost of calling each subroutine or function is in general, non-negligible (regardless of the specific programming language used), unless the compiler(linker) can automatically in-line those functions. I suspect this lack of in-lining by the compiler is the source of significant slowdown that you observed in your codes. With regards to your question number 2, I could not understand it. Perhaps a minimal working example code would be helpful, as @VladimirF and @HighPerformanceMark suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Identifying the cause can be difficult, as can identifying the occurrence of this type of problem.

I suspect that the cacheing of code can improve performance, so that if related routines are spread throughout memory, there "may" be a performance penalty.
Identifying cache related delays is difficult to achieve.

If this is an explanation, then changing the order of routines being added while linking could show some change. Examples of this possible approach are including ddotp near equation reduction and daxpy near equation back substitution could be effective.

Effectively this approach is to link inner loop routines near the calling routine. When developing code, this is often the case.
You have not indicated your approach to linking order; alphabetical would be a bad approach based on this assumption. 
FEM code is better described as polylithic, so this approach should be available. I have experimented with multiple versions of high usage utility routines, placing them in the code, such as duplicate equation solvers for Eigen subspace iteration or direct integration solutions, where inner loops are a high proportion of the solution time.

Experimenting with processors with different memory speed/bandwidth or cache size could provide an interesting comparison.
However, cacheing strategies for memory management to partition arrays should be more productive than experimenting with linking order.

Another issue relates to if the compiler optimises routine calls or if it inlines some trivial routines. You have not indicated your compile options or compiler to identify if this is a possibility.

I hope this answer provides some possible areas to investigate further, while providing no definite explanation for your problem.

Comment: If you know where it is taking more time, then that would be a great start to  figuring out why, and how to fix it.